# Using GPS and/or maps in iphone app

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch

I would like to know if it is possible to pass an address from an SQlite data base to GPS or Google maps and have it show on a map at the press of a button. If anyone is aware of a tuturial that could help me that would be appriciated.

I would also like to get current location and show local places on map, also populated from the same database.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In order to translate address to lat/long coordinate you will have to use the Google directions API since apple is not supporting forward geocoding.

You can take a look at this API - pretty straight forward:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/directions/

Answer (score 0):

for iOS 4.x and below you will need to use the Google API but in iOS 5 Apple has implemented a really nice foreword geocoding API.